# Create a personal shadow ban on all Facebook posts on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I know Instagram allows this but how do I shadow ban a particular user from posting comments on my Facebook page without doing it individually on every post?

Is their a way to do it with the API they provide?

Comment: Just block them? https://www.facebook.com/business/help/354716509063297?id=418112142508425